# Can I throw a catchable exception with Thymeleaf when a template variable is not set?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've implemented a template parser in spring-boot which uses thymeleafs TemplateEngine. The idea is that a user sends template name, locale and any variables used in the template to a controller. The variables are stored in an object called a `ReplaceToken`, which consists of a key and a value. These are then added to the context with the key as variable name and the value as value.

Is there a way to either throw/catch an error when a variable is not set?

Currently, if a variable is missing when the template is processed, Thymeleaf will simply use the placeholder text instead. E.g.

```
<span th:text="${thisVariableDoesntExist}>
Placeholder Text //This will be displayed
</span>
```

I've thought about parsing the entire template post-processing for values I could set beforehand indicating that the placeholder values are still being used, but I would prefer a solution which doesn't have me parse the processed template. I've also looked into somehow using null values, but I couldn't figure out a proper implementation as I will not know what variables should be set.

Comment: A view in MVC does not conceptually do validation. The controller should enforce that the parameters are present.

Comment: This makes sense, but since Thymeleaf throws Errors, if for example a value is null and you're not using the Safe Navigation Operator, I imagined that there might have been a way to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do this on the Controller, maybe by mantaining a static map of required variables for each template, and failing on the redirection if those are not met. Something along the lines of:

```
public class RedirectController {

    private static final Map<String, List<String>> REQUIRED_VARIABLES;
    static {
        REQUIRED_VARIABLES = new HashMap<>();
        REQUIRED_VARIABLES.put("template1", new ArrayList<>());
        REQUIRED_VARIABLES.get("template1").add("name");
        REQUIRED_VARIABLES.get("template1").add("surname");
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    public void redirect(String template, List<ReplaceToken> tokens) {
       for (String requiredVariable : REQUIRED_VARIABLES.get(template)) {
         // maybe overriding ReplaceToken.equals() or something
         if (!tokens.contains(requiredVariable)) { 
           throw new WhateverException("!");
         }
       }

       // ...
    }
}
```

You would have to maintain the `REQUIRED_VARIABLES` map, but at least you could perform the validation on the Controller and avoid parsing templates that would result in errors.